# can't install or remove anything because of cups dependency

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, updates

After I tried to upgrade the kernel of my linux on vps, i get this errors:

When trying to install something

[image: this is for when i try to install sth]

When trying to remove something:

[image: this is for trying to remove sth]

another error:

```
root@berbidvps:~# dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
```

and this is my $PATH:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

if it helps my previous system was ubuntu 14.0.4 and before trying to upgrade the system, I added kali repo to download some kali app. After I ran apt-get upgrade and do-release-upgrade to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS my system got this problem. I removed the kali repo and try to do some fixing, and then these problems happened for me.

Comment: by some tutorials i try to clean my apt-cache but whenever i run apt-get update all the headers got hit. is there anyway to clean those things to make system to download packages from just ubuntu resources?

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal, run the following:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

That will reconfigure your language settings, which seem to be the problem.